# Orleans Multi Region Deployments

Tags: azure, .net-core, actor, orleans

I am looking at using Orleans as a mechanism to help fix concurrency concerns.
I noticed in the later version of Orleans has removed the `MultiCluster` functionality; however its still on their docs.

https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/releases/tag/v3.2.0

What is the recommended approach to hosting two regions in Azure and allowing the Orleans clusters to communicate?

My application will need to ensure that a guid Grain on region A is not getting acted upon at the same time as a Grain in region B with the same guid.

Answer (score 0):

The current implementation of Orleans (3.4.2 as I speak) can't strictly guarantee that a grain with the same Guid won't be [temporarily] duplicated even within a single cluster (in certain cluster failure/recovery scenarios), never mind multiple geographically dispersed clusters. I think your problem is bigger than Orleans.